# Hello World in TensorFlow

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, anaconda

When I tried to run the hello world program in TensorFlow

    `import tensorflow as tf
    hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
    sess = tf.Session()
    print(sess.run(hello))`

I am getting a different formate of output i.e

```
b'Hello, TensorFlow!'
```

but the actual output is

```
Hello, TensorFlow!
```

is it an error? or can I just ignore?
 [TensorFlow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with TensorFlow. What you are facing is a `byte-literal`

To quote the [Python 2.x documentation:](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals)

> A prefix of 'b' or 'B' is ignored in Python 2; it indicates that the
>   literal should become a bytes literal in Python 3 (e.g. when code is
>   automatically converted with 2to3). A 'u' or 'b' prefix may be
>   followed by an 'r' prefix.

The [Python 3.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) states:

> Bytes literals are always prefixed with 'b' or 'B'; they produce an
>   instance of the bytes type instead of the str type. They may only
>   contain ASCII characters; bytes with a numeric value of 128 or greater
>   must be expressed with escapes.

I would also recommend reading the following [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html), this will clear a lot of possible doubts about printing, handling strings in Python.